# How to increase the accuracy of my model fitting using Scipy Optimization

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, model-fitting

I want to make a curve fitting of the following data:
[munich_temperatures_average.txt](https://github.com/vuillaut/datascience_intro/blob/main/Scipy/data/munich_temperatures_average.txt)

I have tried:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def func(temp, a, b, c):
    return a * np.cos(2 * np.pi * temp + b) + c

date, temperature = np.loadtxt('munich_temperatures_average.txt', unpack=True)

result = optimize.curve_fit(func, date, temperature)

plt.plot(date, temperature, '.')
plt.plot(date, func(date, result[0][0], result[0][1], result[0][2]), c='red', zorder=10)
plt.ylim([-20, 30])
plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("Temperature", fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

But as you can see in the output image, the **oscillation magnitude** of the model after fitting seems to be **less** than the actual, can you please tell me how can I make the fitting more accurate? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That fit doesn't actually look out of the question. Your point density is possibly such that it's much higher away from the peak than at the peak.

Comment: A better fit inspection would zoom into one cycle.

Comment: If you are assuming a sinusoidal response, it's pretty safe to guess the period is exactly one year, then you should be able to do a linear fit rather than using the nonlinear optimization.

Comment: @Reinderien density inspection (Histogram) confirms your hypothesis, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Reinderien explanation, I used [1D median filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html) to filter outliers, hence the model fitting seems to be accurate:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.signal import medfilt

def func(temp, a, b, c):
    return a * np.cos(2 * np.pi * temp + b) + c

date, temperature = np.loadtxt('./data/munich_temperatures_average.txt', unpack=True)
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, date, temperature)

# Median Filter
filtered = medfilt(temperature, 21)
for i in range(10):
    filtered = medfilt(filtered, 21)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6), dpi=80)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
# ax1.subplot(121)
ax1.hist(temperature, color = "lightblue", ec="green", bins=150, orientation="horizontal")

x1 = np.linspace(0, 0, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(20, 20, 100)
y  = np.linspace(0, 400, 100)
ax1.plot(y, x1, 'r--', linewidth=1, markersize=1)
ax1.plot(y, x2, 'r--', linewidth=1, markersize=1)

ax1.set_ylim([-20, 30])
ax1.set_ylabel("Temperature", fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel("Frequency", fontsize=14)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax2.plot(date, temperature, '.', zorder=0, label='data', alpha=0.1)
ax2.plot(date, func(date, *popt),'m', zorder=10, label='model')
ax2.set_ylim([-20, 30])
ax2.set_xlabel("Year", fontsize=14)
# ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature", fontsize=14)
ax2.legend(loc='best')

popt2, pcov2 = optimize.curve_fit(func, date, filtered)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)
ax3.plot(date, filtered, '.', zorder=0, label='filtered data')
# ax3.plot(date, func(date, *popt2),'m', zorder=10, label='model')
ax3.set_ylim([-20, 30])
ax3.set_xlabel("Year", fontsize=14)
# ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature", fontsize=14)
ax3.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]